# How to use prawn on maglev

Tags: ruby, prawn, maglev

Being new to maglev I wanted to start with a small, but still useful example. So i decided to start moving the ruby classes I use to generate my invoices to maglev. However I ran in an unexpected problem using the (excellent) prawn PDF-library.

Being on rvm I generated a gemset for the application which is setup in a .rvmrc for the invoice directory. It gets used when I cd into it:

```
Using /Users/patru/.rvm/gems/maglev-head with gemset invoice
```

When I install prawn everything starts out fine, the gem seems to be installed and the ri-docs are being generated. However, trouble starts when rdoc should be created, the maglev provided gem command gives me

```
 gem install prawn
[INFO] The MagLev team publishes customized versions of some gems.
...
Successfully installed prawn-0.12.0
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for prawn-0.12.0...


RDoc failure in lib/prawn/images/jpg.rb at or around line 20 column 26

Before reporting this, could you check that the file
you're documenting compiles cleanly--RDoc is not a
full Ruby parser, and gets confused easily if fed
invalid programs.

The internal error was:

ERROR:  While generating documentation for prawn-0.12.0
... MESSAGE:   global $@ is a read-only variable
... RDOC args: --ri --op /Users/patru/.rvm/gems/maglev-head@invoice/doc/prawn-0.12.0/ri --title Prawn Documentation --main README -q lib README.md LICENSE COPYING GPLv2 GPLv3 --title prawn-0.12.0 Documentation --quiet
a RubySystemExit occurred (error 2752)
```

No big deal to live without documentation, it is good enough, but something else seems to go wrong, gem list says

```
Ascii85 (1.0.1)
bundler (1.0.21)
erector (0.8.3)
pdf-reader (0.10.1)
polyglot (0.3.3)
prawn (0.12.0)
rake (0.9.2)
treetop (1.4.10)
ttfunk (1.0.3)
```

so all seems to be well, but if I do

```
require 'ruby gems'
require 'prawn'
```

in irb (which works perfectly on my ree-1.8.7) I get a strange

```
NoMethodError: NoMethodError: undefined method `ruby_18' for 
from /Users/patru/.rvm/gems/maglev-head@invoice/gems/prawn-0.12.0/lib/prawn/core/object_store.rb:246:in `__compileClass'
from /Users/patru/.rvm/gems/maglev-head@invoice/gems/prawn-0.12.0/lib/prawn/core/object_store.rb:14:in `__compileClass'
from /Users/patru/.rvm/gems/maglev-head@invoice/gems/prawn-0.12.0/lib/prawn/core/object_store.rb:13:in `__compileClass'
from /Users/patru/.rvm/gems/maglev-head@invoice/gems/prawn-0.12.0/lib/prawn/core/object_store.rb:12
from /Users/patru/.rvm/rubies/maglev-head/src/kernel/bootstrap/Kernel.rb:831:in `gem_original_require'
from /Users/patru/.rvm/rubies/maglev-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /Users/patru/.rvm/rubies/maglev-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:57:in `require'
from /Users/patru/.rvm/gems/maglev-head@invoice/gems/prawn-0.12.0/lib/prawn/core.rb:78
from /Users/patru/.rvm/rubies/maglev-head/src/kernel/bootstrap/Kernel.rb:831:in `gem_original_require'
from /Users/patru/.rvm/rubies/maglev-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /Users/patru/.rvm/rubies/maglev-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:57:in `require'
from /Users/patru/.rvm/gems/maglev-head@invoice/gems/prawn-0.12.0/lib/prawn.rb:11
from /Users/patru/.rvm/rubies/maglev-head/src/kernel/bootstrap/Kernel.rb:831:in `gem_original_require'
from /Users/patru/.rvm/rubies/maglev-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `require'
from /Users/patru/.rvm/rubies/maglev-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:57:in `require'
from /Users/patru/.rvm/rubies/maglev-head/src/kernel/bootstrap/Kernel.rb:831:in `gem_original_require'
from /Users/patru/.rvm/rubies/maglev-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /Users/patru/.rvm/rubies/maglev-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:57:in `require'
from (irb):5:in `__compileEval'
from (irb):7:in `__compileEval'
from /Users/patru/.rvm/rubies/maglev-head/src/kernel/bootstrap/Kernel.rb:394:in `eval'
from /Users/patru/.rvm/rubies/maglev-head/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:159:in `eval_input'
...
```

I am probably missing something obvious here. Suffice it to say that the 'erector' gem I installed as well (see the gem list above) can be required without problems, so I do not do everything wrong ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be an interaction with irb.  I can run the following script and it creates the correct pdf file:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'prawn'

Prawn::Document.generate('hello.pdf') do
  text "Hello! from #{RUBY_ENGINE}"
end
```

It's probably best to file bug reports at https://github.com/maglev/maglev/issues

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, it works for me to. I will file it as a bug in the github issues. Of course, being new to maglev I supposed the error was entirely mine.